# Help for Integral and evaluating - Eikonal equation

Tags: real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Hy guys I'm reading a paper of

"Finding Exact Solutions to the Two- Dimensional Eikonal Equation" - E.D. Moskalensky.

link for the paper: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1134%2FS1995423909020074#page-1

I'm not understand the equation (7) this integral is an line integral? Who is AB?

Also I'm not understood the manipulation

$f= \int_{AB}\;\; \phi cosu\;dx +\phi sinu\;dy\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(7)$

where $\phi=\; \dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{\sqrt{(x+a)^2+y^2}}$
$u= tan^{-1}(\frac{x}{y})\;-\;tan^{-1}(\frac{(x+a)}{y})$

so, using $(7)$ $f= x - \frac{a}{2}ln((x+a)^2+y^2)$

Since already appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use elementary trig to expand the expressions
$$
\cos\bigl(\tan^{-1}(a/b)-\tan^{-1}(c/d)\bigr)\qquad
\sin\bigl(\tan^{-1}(a/b)-\tan^{-1}(c/d)\bigr),
$$
you'll see that they become (with the right sign assumptions)
$$
\frac{(ac+bd)}{\sqrt(a^2+b^2)\sqrt(c^2+d^2)} \qquad
\frac{(ad-bc)}{\sqrt(a^2+b^2)\sqrt(c^2+d^2)}
$$
respectively.  Now use these identities to simplify the above line integral.  Then you'll see that it's an exact differential and the rest should be clear